# Displaying table header in multiple page using Aspose words

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

Currently I'm working with exporting reports using Aspose Words in Java. I'm populating table with dynamic data but my main problem is when data reaches next page there is no header in exported docs. How can I get header for all pages in the exported file. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this issue in **JAVA** in the following way:

1.Load the document

```
Document doc =  new Document(getMyDir() + "Table.SimpleTable.doc");
```

2.Get the first table

```
Table table = doc.getChild(NodeType.TABLE, 0, true); //i.e. second   parenthesis as index of table in doc file
```

3. Get the rows which  is used for heading of table

```
Row rows = (Row) table.getRows().get(0);//we can set multiple rows as heading by passing it's index
```

4. set the rows as **HeadingFormat** = *true*

```
rows.getRowFormat().setHeadingFormat(true);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I have edit the above mentioned answer. Please look through this.

Comment: Works smoothly on my Aspose words. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

---

1. Select the header portion (row/rows) to be repeated in the template.
2. Right click it. Go to table properties and select row tab where there is a second option as "Repeat as header row at the top of each page".

Comment: Thanks Prabin... It really helped